# importing folder that shadows same name as third party dependency. What to do?

Tags: python-3.x, import

say I have a folder structure that looks like this:

```
.
├── CODEOWNERS
├── Makefile
├── README.rst
├── __pycache__
│   └── conftest.cpython-37-pytest-6.2.2.pyc
├── airflow
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── dags
│   └── <some_file_I_need>
```

how do I import the file I need from the airflow local package (not the third party dependency named `airflow`). I have a dependency called `airflow` unfortunately and that gets imported when I do: `import airflow.dev...` and that errors out.

Comment: Can you rename the folder?

Comment: No I cannot rename it easily without lots of stuff potentially breaking